# Centos Python2.7 YUM Dependency Resolution with Python2.7

Tags: linux, python-2.7, centos

I am trying to use a Centos box for a Vagrant VM (because I think it’s the closest thing to an AWS Amazon Linux machine).

## **The Problem**

Amazon Linux has python2.6 as the system python but there’s also a python2.7 package available with the Amazon repo.

Centos does’t have a python2.7 package available.

I can’t resolve python2.7 dependencies when yum installing particular packages.

## **Things I have tried**

1. Using the SCL python27 - As far as I can tell, it only works with an SCL bash session and doesn’t resolve dependencies when using yum to install packages.
2. Downloading python2.7 and building an RPM package (using FPM) to locally install using yum and rpm - This successfully installs python2.7 but it does not resolve dependency failures
3. I also have a repo on my host machine (running Fedora) to hold all my custom rpm packages. I copied the rpm I created on the Centos VM to the repo and although it does install, it also does not resolve the dependency failure either.

I am now out of ideas so any help would be appreciated.

## Example Dependency Error

This is the YUM error I get when trying to install a package.  I get this when using an scl python27 shell too.

```
Error: Package: python27-djangorestframework-2.3.7-1.noarch (WFRepo)
    Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
    Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201508042137.x86_64/6.7)
        python(abi) = 2.6
```

Comment: What are the dependency errors you see, when you tried the SCL repository?

Comment: @RaviTezu I am getting the following

`
Error: Package: python27-djangorestframework-2.3.7-1.noarch (WFRepo)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
           Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201508042137.x86_64/6.7)
               python(abi) = 2.6
`

This is what I always get when I say it doesn't resolve dependency issues.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution eventually.

The first 30 odd Google searches tell me to make and alt install python2.7 BUT after further searching, I found [THIS](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-epel-and-additional-repositories-on-centos-and-red-hat/) which I thought was just instructions on how to enable the handy epel repo but it also includes instructions on how to install the IUS repo.

I didn't think the IUS repo was very handy (never heard of it before and wasn't mentioned in anything I'd read up to that point) but I was running out of ideas so I looked into it and installed it just to see what was available.  Turns out, it has python27!

Below is what I did to install the IUS repo and python27:

Make sure you have the epel repo installed/enabled.

```
# wget https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
# rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
# yum install python27
```

Make sure it is installing from the @ius repo and not base or update.  If not installing from ius, you will need to use `—disablerepo='*' —enablerepo='ius'` options for the yum install.

After the install, I had python2.7 alongside the system python2.6 and all my dependency issues were resolved.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

The response given by 'WhiteFile' helped me to resolve my python 2.6 (abi) issue. I was trying to install Cassandra 3.11 which having the dependency on python 2.7.x and I built it using make/make altinstall and changed the ~/bash_profile with alias and path but it did not help. I was still getting the following error

```
   [root@test~]# yum install cassandra
   Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
   Setting up Install Process
   Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
   * base: centos.myfahim.com
   * extras: centos.myfahim.com
   * updates: centos.myfahim.com
   Resolving Dependencies
   --> Running transaction check
   ---> Package cassandra.noarch 0:3.11.4-1 will be installed
   --> Processing Dependency: python(abi) >= 2.7 for package: cassandra-3.11.4-1.noarch
   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
   Error: Package: cassandra-3.11.4-1.noarch (cassandra)
          Requires: python(abi) >= 2.7
          Installed: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201703281317.x86_64/6.9)
          python(abi) = 2.6
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The suggestion did not work as given by yum.

I followed the approach referred by 'WhiteFire' user but added one more error as shown below and I resolved it by adding one more command

```
warning: ius-release.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 9cd4953f: NOKEY 
error: Failed dependencies:
    epel-release = 6 is needed by ius-release-1.0-15.ius.centos6.noarch
```

I installed epel-release using yum

```
wget https://centos6.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
yum install  epel-release
rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
yum install python27
```

I am yet to resolve the output from below command as it still refer python(abi) => 2.6

```
     rpm -q --provides python | grep abi
```